# In Play, how do I include custom query parameters in a reverse-routed URL? (Call)

Tags: scala, playframework

With a route like:

```
GET /users/:id   controllers.Users.view(id)
```

In the controller, I can read a custom `backTo` query string param like this:

```
def view (id: String) = Action {r =>
  val backTo = r.getQueryString("backTo") // read custom param
  ...
}
```

Assuming `backTo` is an optional query string parameter that I don't want to include in the routes definition (maybe all the actions can read it).

How do I construct a URL using reverse-routing that includes the `backTo` parameter?

I would expect something like:

```
routes.Users.view(id).withQueryString("backTo" -> Seq("previous"))
```

But that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just pimping a `withQueryString` method onto `Call` that just parses the URL and rebuilds the URL with the extra parameters:

```
implicit class CallOps (c: Call) {
  import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.{QueryStringDecoder, QueryStringEncoder}
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  def withQueryString(query: (String,Seq[String])*): Call = {
    val decoded = new QueryStringDecoder(c.url)
    val newUrl = new QueryStringEncoder(decoded.getPath)
    val params = decoded.getParameters.asScala.mapValues(_.asScala.toSeq).toSeq
    for {
      (key, values) <- params ++ query
      value <- values
    } newUrl.addParam(key, value)
    Call(c.method, newUrl.toString, c.fragment)
  }
}
```

And now I can use it like this:

```
routes.Users.view(id).withQueryString("backTo" -> Seq("previous")).url
```

I wish I didn't have to re-parse the URL, but by the time I have a `Call`, the URL has already been constructed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to come down to `String` level as there is really no such method available (yet).

What the reverse router is giving you is actually a `play.api.mvc.Call` object. You can take a look at the source here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.0/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L359

You will see that you can get the `absoluteURL()` - which returns you a `String` - from here you would have to manipulate it by adding your query parameter:

`val url = routes.Users.view(id).absoluteURL() + "?backTo=home"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires me to re-parse the URL, since I can't (shouldn't?) make the assumption here that the "id" parameter is a path parameter (implementation detail)... if the route is changed, could end up with an invalid URL like: "/users?id=24?backTo=home"

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco if you'll keep correct order of the routes (`GET /users ...` first `GET /users/:id ...` later) double question mark will not occur, anyway, using valid routing syntax IMHO is still much safer

Comment: @biesior My point is that reverse routing should insulate me from having to worry about the actual implementation of the route. Changing a single route from using a `path param` to using a `query param` should not silently start producing invalid URLs

Comment: OK, now I see your point of view, in that case you have 2 solutions -re-parsing the URLs or using named params in reverse routes, both are NOT ideal.. (personally i'd choose the second, but that's matter of taste)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong about using [**Parameters with default values**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting#Parameters-with-default-values) (without resolving it manually by yourself)? sample:

```
def view(id: String, backTo: String, forwardTo: String, whatever: String) = Action {
  Ok(
    "ID: " + id
      + ", backTo: " + backTo
      + ", forwardTo: " + forwardTo
      + ", whatever: " + whatever
  )
}
```

route:

```
GET  /users/:id  controllers.Users.view(id, backTo ?= null, forwardTo ?= null, whatever ?= null)
```

it allows you to make reverse routes with only ID as a required param:

```
// /users/john-doe
routes.Users.view("john-doe")
```

by ordered params:

```
// /users/john-doe?backTo=prev&forwardTo=next&whatever=bar
routes.Users.view("john-doe", "prev", "next", "bar")
```

or only with named optional params:

```
// /users/john-doe?whatever=baz
routes.Users.view("john-doe", whatever = "baz")
```

What's more important it's type-safe as it's absolutely under the Play's routing syntax, without any manual manipulation. Also you don't need to care if you should start your params with `?` or `&` char: `"?backTo=home"` vs. `"&backTo=home"`...

Comment: Note that I don't want to have to include it in the routes file since it can be available in all of the pages (way too much repetition). I would have expected there to be a `.withQueryString(...)` method in `Call`, just like there's a `.withFragment(...)` method. Presumably, if there a way to read the value (`r.getQueryString(...)`) there should be a way to put it there, no?

Comment: _way too much repetition_, could you explain? isn't the syntax `routes.Users.view("john-doe", whatever = "baz")` right for you fears?

Comment: If I have 40 routes, all of them potentially taking an optional `backTo` parameter, then I have to put that parameter in every single one (in the routes definition, that's where the repetition is).

Comment: Otherwise you need to handle them potentially in 40 actions, don't you?